# Use Ant to find file with latest version number

Tags: file, search, ant

I want to use ant to find the file with the latest version number. For example, I have a file directory named tomcat with the following files:

- apache-tomcat-6.0.37.zip
- apache-tomcat-6.0.38.zip
- apache-tomcat-6.0.39.zip

I want ant to determine that apache-tomcat-6.0.39.zip is the latest file. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use resource collections, see [last](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#last) and [sort](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#sort). f.e. :

```
<project>

 <path id="foo">
  <last>
    <sort>
      <fileset dir="C:/some/path" includes="**/apache-tomcat-*.zip"/>
    </sort>
  </last>
 </path>

  <echo>$${foo} => ${toString:foo}</echo>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] ${foo} => C:\some\path\apache-tomcat-6.0.39.zip
```

Comment: Works for me and I find this solution cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

- use `<pathconvert>`to get file names from the relevant `<fileset>`.
- use `<sortlist>` to sort the filenames in *`natural String order`*.
- pick the **last** filename from the list.

try this:

```
<fileset dir="${your.base.dir}" id="one">
   <include name="**/apache-tomcat-.*.zip"/>
</fileset>
<pathconvert property="orig.list" refid="one" pathsep=","/>
<sortlist property="sorted.list" value="${orig.list}" delimiter="," />
<propertyregex property="result" input="${sorted.list}" regexp=",?([^,]+?)$" select="\1"/>
```

inputList: `<property name="one" value="a.b-2,a.b-5,a.b-1,a.b-3,a.b-4"/>`
outputList: `[echo] a.b-5`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me.

`<echo>result: ${result}</echo>`
`[echo] result: ${result}`

I also added this to the beginning of the build file so that <sortlist> task would work:

`<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"><classpath><pathelement location="lib/ant-contrib-0.6.jar" /></classpath></taskdef>`

Comment: and for debugging, insert `<echo>` for `${orig.list}` and `${sorted.list}` as well. probably, the issue is with the `<fileset>` generation.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I changed `<include name="**/apache-tomcat-.*.zip"/>` to `<include name="**/apache-tomcat-*.zip"/>` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: `-*.zip` technically means that you're trying to match `0 or more of the character " - "`

Comment: According to Ant, the pattern is similar to that used in DOS or UNIX. [link](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html) So it's not the same as regular expression pattern.